# Javascript XMLHttpRequest mouseover event listener

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a webpage that will list the captions for each picture. Each time you mouse over the caption, the corresponding picture will be displayed in an area below it. The caption shows, but when I hover the caption it doesn't display the image.

Since the ‘XMLHTTPRequest’ object has difficulties identifying a picture. I created a very simple webpage with one line containing the `<img>` tag that will list the location of the picture. (e.g. `<img src="img/cacao.jpg" alt="" id="cacao1">`) so the ‘XMLHTTPRequest’ object will look for an HTML page rather than a *.jpg file. so inside of cacao1.html, cacao2.html, cacao3.html and cacao4.html, there is one line of `<img>` tag.

*chocolate1, chocolate2, chocolate3 and chocolate4 is a id for my figcaption.*

This is my Javascript.

```
window.addEventListener("load", registerListeners, false);
var asynchrequest;

function registerListeners() {

    var img;
    img=document.getElementById("chocolate1");
    img.addEventListener("mouseover", function () { getContent ("cacao1.html");}, false);
    img.addEventListener("mouseout", clearContent, false);
    img=document.getElementById("chocolate2");
    img.addEventListener("mouseover", function () { getContent("cacao2.html");}, false);
    img.addEventListener("mouseout", clearContent, false);
    img=document.getElementById("chocolate3");
    img.addEventListener("mouseover", function () { getContent("cacao3.html");}, false);
    img.addEventListener("mouseout", clearContent, false);
    img=document.getElementById("chocolate4");
    img.addEventListener("mouseover", function () { getContent("cacao4.html");}, false);
    img.addEventListener("mouseout", clearContent, false);
}

function getContent(infopage) {

        asynchrequest= new XMLHttpRequest();
        asynchrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (asynchrequest.readyState == 4 && asynchrequest.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = asynchrequest.responseText;
    }
  };
  asynchrequest.open("GET", infopage, true);
  asynchrequest.send();
}


function clearContent() {

    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="";

}
```

Comment: are there any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: @JaromandaX   1) The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. 2) The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
Chocolate.html
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: file:///C:/Users/791894/Desktop/CPRG256_%20%20Website%20Development/CPRG256_Lab10/PartA/cacao3.html
Line Number 1, Column 47:

Comment: can you post, in the question, not as  a comment, the contents of `cacao3.html`

Comment: how is this part html code, i think they are better JS to with...

Comment: @JaromandaX I only have one single line of <img>tag. This is what I have as a content of cacao3.html -> <img src="img/cacao3.jpg" alt=""  id="cacao3">

Comment: oh ... `file:///` protocol too ... that's going to cause all sorts of issues